# DataGridView control scrolls to top when a property changed

Tags: c#, datagridview

On a Windows Form I have a `DataGridView` control with records that is filled by a data source (data binding). Each record presents a data object.

Not all the rows are displaying: only the first 10 for example. So the user can scroll down to see the another records. Nothing special about this.

But when a user clicks on a row after scrolling, a data property of the object of row is changing and this refreshes the `DataGridViewand` - it "scrolls" to top of datagrid (maybe the whole `DataGridView` is refreshing). This is not desirable.

How can I keep the current scroll position during a record update?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the DataGridView's [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex(VS.90).aspx) property.

It gets/sets the index of the first row displayed on your DGV.

Use it like this:

```
        int rowIndex = dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;

        // Refresh your DGV.

        dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowIndex;
```

Of course this won't work quite right if sort or add/remove rows to your DGV (you did say you were updating so maybe you're OK).

Comment: I had the same problem. I found that it's the call to AcceptChanges() on my DataSource that does it, so I fixed it by saving the value of FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex before the call and restoring it afterwards.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue, however, I'm a little confused as to where to put the above suggestion of Jay's. I've tried it in several spots and doesn't seem to be making any difference. I've also tried putting the call to AcceptChanges() on my DataSource, before and after it is set to the DataGridView, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Using this solution I had to check if the gridview's `Rows.Count` was above 0, and then set it to `rowIndex`, otherwise I got outofrange exceptions, even with checking conditions and compensating for that they still arose, until I realised if there were no rows I could just let the gridview handle itself and scroll to the top.